# Scentific approach to evaluting software

Tags: rest, jira

I'm currently in school and have been tasked with objectively evaluating a software (atlassians Jira platform). I'm currently having issues in staying objective. For example, saying that the platform is "easy to use" is according to my opinion of the platform and not so much based on evidence. So I'm curious to hear from you guys if you know if any scientific method to evaluate software or services? I've currently done a survey asking users how they use Jira and what they think about the platform. But I feel that this is not enough I would like to have some numbers that can point to how good or bad the software is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fist thing to mention is that a scientific work is always a collective work. Keep in mind that others might already have done such an scientific work you might use. So you have to create a small team or look for well-founded scientific work throu the internet or contacts in universities if you have such contacts.

If there are no results that fits you have to create knowledge. In this case a mathematical based decision will help. The Decisiontable might be the source for a scientifc decisions. The [Decisiontable](https://www.azaig.de/dt.html) requires a couple of possible decisions, a couple of factors to respect in a specific weight. It contains the analysis and synthesis. After you have created the Decisiontable you should discus it in a critical team until the team agrees the results (and might offer them to the public).